# Сохранение данных пользователя

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Пишу первую программу с нормальным функционалом, а не лабы для универа. Нужен совет опытных программистов. Столкнулся с потребностью сохранения данных.

Данные (`string, int, bool`) хранятся в объекте, а объекты хранятся в коллекции `List`.

Подскажите, куда их лучше записывать перед закрытием программы? Слышал про ini-файлы, двоичные файлы и БД. С чем лучше (а именно, правильней) работать? Возможно есть ещё какие-нибудь варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ini-файле сохраняются настройки программы.
В файлах и базах данных - пользовательские данные.